# How can I find the ID of the variable that has the maximum value in CLIPS?

Tags: max, clips

I tried to find the best student according to their exam marks. I took them from the user. I want CLIPS to give me the ID of the best student. For example, student1 mark 70, student2 mark 80 and student 3 mark 100. CLIPS should tell me "The best student is ... because his/her point is ..." I used global variables but I'm not sure if it's true because it doesn't work.

```
(defglobal ?*student1mark* = 0)
(defglobal ?*student2mark* = 0)
(defglobal ?*student3mark* = 0)

(defrule get-marks
=>
(printout t "What is the exam mark of student1?" crlf)
(bind ?*student1mark* (read))
(assert (stu1mark ?*student1mark*))
(printout t "What is the exam mark of student2?" crlf)
(bind ?*student2mark* (read))
(assert (stu2mark ?*student2mark*))
(printout t "What is the exam mark of student3?" crlf)
(bind ?*student3mark* (read))
(assert (stu3mark ?*student3mark*))
(build (str-cat
        "(deffacts students (student student1 " ?*student1mark* " student student2 " ?*student2mark* " student student3 " ?*student3mark* "))")))

(defrule whichstudent
(student ?ID = (max ?*student1mark*" ?*student2mark*" ?*student3mark*))
=>
(printout t "The best student is " ?ID crlf))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use global variables. I would go with a template and facts.
One solution with the help of a rule would be this:

```
         CLIPS (6.30 3/17/15)
CLIPS> (deftemplate student
    (slot id (type INTEGER) (default ?NONE))
    (slot mark (type INTEGER) (default ?NONE))
)
CLIPS> (deffacts students
    (student (id 1) (mark 80))
    (student (id 2) (mark 79))
    (student (id 4) (mark 60))
    (student (id 3) (mark 90))
)
CLIPS> (defrule best-mark
    (compare-students)
    (student (id ?id) (mark ?mark))
    (not 
        (student (id ?) (mark ?nmark&:(> ?nmark ?mark)))
    )
=>
    (printout t "The best student is student no. " ?id crlf)
)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (compare-students))
<Fact-5>
CLIPS> (run)
The best student is student no. 3
```

The key part is

```
    (student (id ?id) (mark ?mark))
    (not 
        (student (id ?) (mark ?nmark&:(> ?nmark ?mark)))
    )
```

So this rule matches with a student fact, if there is no other student with a higher mark.

Comment: Sure, assert student facts with the according id and the mark you enter.